# Update x columns from many rows in a different table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table of products which looks like this:

```
Products (companyID int, product1 int, product2 int ... product8 int)
```

and a table of product details like so:

```
ProductDetails (companyID int productID int)
```

My ProductDetails table has (at most) 8 rows of products for each companyID.

I would like to update the Products table where the products in each row (8 of them) get the values of products from the ProductDetails table rows where Products.companyID = ProductDetails.companyID

Is there a way to do this without a loop (i.e one update command)?

EDIT:

so the idea is that the Products table contains only the company information (no product info) and the ProductDetails table contains info about 1-8 products / company.

SO one update command should update the Products table for each row (product1, product2 ... product8) with any products found in the ProductDetails table for each company.

Comment: How can you tell which row in `ProductDetails` should go to which `ProductX` column in `Products`?

Comment: rows 1-8 that have the same companyID:

where Products.companyID = ProductDetails.companyID

The ProductDetails table contains a max number of 8 products, but it's not guaranteed to have all 8 products, in which case it should just insert nulls for missing products.

Comment: Order of rows in RDMBS is not preserved, so question remains what row (out of 8 or less) that belong to particular CompanyId should go to product1, product2 and so on?

Comment: Ok, I see. That does not matter. They can go in any order as long as they belong to the same company.

Comment: Please show sample data and desired results. Word problems weren't fun in high school and they're no more exciting now.

Comment: sure, no problem.

Products
----------------------------------------------

1203, Apple, 123 Apple Street, California, 'iPad', 'iPhone', 'iWhatever'...
7707, Microsoft, 123 Money Street, Washington, 'Ms Office, 'Visual Studio'...


ProductDetails
----------------------------
1203 'iPad',
1203 'iPhone'
1203 'iWhatever'
7707 'Ms Office'
7707 'Visual Studio'

This is simplified, since there are a few other fields, but it should show what I'm asking for. Thank you.

Comment: Please edit that into your question; nobody can read it in a comment.

Comment: so the idea is that the Products table contains only the company information (no product info) and the ProductDetails table contains info about 1-8 products / company.

SO one update command should update the Products table for each row (products 1-8) with any products found in the ProductDetails table for each company.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to pivot the data into the table, allowing for 8 columns.  The example below populates 8 products, if there are more, they simple don't get inserted anywhere.

```
create table company (
    companyid int,
    name varchar(100));
insert company values (1203, 'Apple');
insert company values (7707, 'Microsoft');
create table products (
    companyid int,
    product1 varchar(100),
    product2 varchar(100),
    product3 varchar(100),
    product4 varchar(100),
    product5 varchar(100),
    product6 varchar(100),
    product7 varchar(100),
    product8 varchar(100));
create table productdetails (
    companyid int,
    product varchar(100));
insert into productdetails values (1203, 'iPad');
insert into productdetails values (1203, 'iPhone');
insert into productdetails values (1203, 'iPod');
insert into productdetails values (7707, 'Visual Studio');
insert into productdetails values (7707, 'Office');


insert products
select *
  from (
select companyid, product, rn=row_number() over (partition by companyid order by product)
  from productdetails
) source
pivot (max(product) for rn in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8])) pv;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely a bad design. There should only one `ProductID` column in `Product`s table.
But as long as you use this structure you can use this ugly solution (SQL Server 2005+).

```
declare @Products table(companyID int, product1 int, product2 int, product3 int,product4 int,product5 int,product6 int,product7 int, product8 int)
declare @ProductDetails table(companyID int, productID int)

insert into @Products (companyID) values (1)

insert into @ProductDetails (companyID,productID) values (1,17015),(1,278465),(1,3554646)

;with cte as
(
    select companyID, productID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY companyID ORDER BY ProductID) nmb
    from @ProductDetails
)
UPDATE p
SET product1= c1.productID,
    product2= c2.productID,
    product3= c3.productID
    ...
FROM @Products p
     left join cte c1 ON c1.companyID=p.companyID AND c1.nmb=1
     left join cte c2 ON c2.companyID=p.companyID AND c2.nmb=2
     left join cte c3 ON c3.companyID=p.companyID AND c3.nmb=3 
     ...

SELECT * FROM @Products
```